# How can I replicate the Digg login errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, digg

I'd like to replicate the Digg login errors. At http://www.digg.com if you click on Login or Join Digg, and press continue without filling out any fields, it looks like they are using jQuery with the slidedown function to display the errors above the form.

How hard would it be to do something like this? What should I read to help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to replicate this using the [jQuery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) library. It has the ability validate forms, and place the resulting errors anywhere in the DOM.

Then it would only be a matter of applying the correct CSS styling and jQuery to make the errors appear and provide the interactivity.

Answer (score -1):

They are probably using Javascript to perform a [tween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweening) on a CSS property, such as `top`.  If you're familiar to CSS, you can skip straight to JS.

Tutorials:

- [jQuery for designers](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/)
- [Mootools Effects Quickstart Guide](http://www.broken-links.com/2007/05/01/a-mootools-quickstart-guide/)

Docs:

- [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)
- [Mootools Fx](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx)